# Move committed changes from trunk to branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have several commits at the head of my repositories trunk that contain an initial implementation of a feature that the customer has decided to defer to a future revision.

Is there a clean way to relocate them to a branch and completely remove them from the history that is shown when a user looks at `/trunk/myApp/`, or is the best I can do to create a new branch containing what is currently the most recent version on trunk and then do a new checkin with a copy of the code from before work on the feature started?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subversion doesn't support Git-style rebasing.  (Nor would you want to use it in the case where the changes exist on a shared public branch.)  So you've got it about right - save off the changes you're interested in in a new branch, then do a reverse merge on trunk to undo those commits.  See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo.